# sapply in R over a vector with individual elements of another vector

Tags: r, sapply, euclidean-distance

I have two vectors `x` and `cen`. Say the length of `x` is `10` and the length of `cen` is `3`. I want to find the Euclidean distance between `x` and individual points of `cen`.

The Euclidean distance function is defined as : `euc.dist <- function(x1, x2) sqrt(sum((x1 - x2) ^ 2))`

I saw that sapply works with the negation `"-"` operator like so:

```
> x 
 [1] 23  4 65  8  9 23 90 76 55  7
> cen
 [1] 23  4 65
> sapply(x,"-",cen)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    0  -19   42  -15  -14    0   67   53   32   -16
[2,]   19    0   61    4    5   19   86   72   51     3
[3,]  -42  -61    0  -57  -56  -42   25   11  -10   -58
```

Here each each value within the `cen` vector operates over whole `x` vector.

But when I try to use the `euc.dist` function instead of `"-"` then I only get a single vector as an output instead of a 3x10 matrix.

```
> sapply(x,"euc.dist",cen)
 [1]  46.09772  63.89053  74.06079  59.07622  57.93962  46.09772 111.84811  90.07774  61.03278  60.24118
```

Any reasons as to why this is happening? Do I need to define the euc.dist function in a different manner? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your code is basically doing this: `sapply(1:length(x),function(m) euc.dist(x[m],cen))`

It is applying the `euc.dist` function to each `x` element to the entirety of the vector `cen`.

One solution is to line your `x` and `cen` vectors so that you have corresponding `x1` and `x2` values to plug into `euc.dist`.

Comment: @road_to_quantdom: ah, I get what's happening now. I am sorry, I do not understand what you mean by "line `x` and `cen` vectors"

Comment: Look at the `outer` function, e.g. `outer(cen,x,"-")`

Comment: @MaratTalipov `outer` does work for the `"-"` operation but `outer(cen,x,"euc.dist")` gives the following error - `Error in outer(cen, x, euc.dist) : dims [product 30] do not match the length of object [1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `euc.dist` function is not vectorize, as could be easily tested by:

```
euc.dist(x[1],cen)
[1] 46.09772
```

whereas what you probably want is:

```
> Vectorize(euc.dist)(x[1],cen)
[1]  0 19 42
```

(Use `?Vectorize` for the details).

So, in your case a simple solution would be:

```
> sapply(x,Vectorize(euc.dist),cen)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    0   19   42   15   14    0   67   53   32    16
[2,]   19    0   61    4    5   19   86   72   51     3
[3,]   42   61    0   57   56   42   25   11   10    58
```

Comment: I see. So the function `Vectorize()` is a wrapper for mapply. This will do nicely. Thanks a lot! I did not realize that operations like `"-"` and others are vectorized by definition while `euc.dist` is not.

Comment: I've never used the Vectorize here before, and I was amazed I hadn't. Is it even necessary to use sapply? if I define `seqv1 <- function(x,y) Vectorize(seq)(y,x)` and then `seqv2 <- function(x,y) Vectorize(seqv1)(y,x)` Would this just vectorize both?

Answer (score 1):

how about this?
since you want all factor combinations

```
datas <- expand.grid(x = x,cen = cen)
datas$euclid = apply(datas,1,function(rowval) euc.dist(rowval[1], rowval[2]))
```

Comment: Thanks! This workaround does work. However I will be working with vector `x` that will be in the length of hundreds of thousands whereas `cen` will be small. Expanding the data in this manner will increase that data size too much.